# How to restore a recovery partition? Or create one

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

So I'm going to show you a cloned-drive.  It boots just fine.  But there is also, shall I say,  'Hanging-Chads' included with it

[Partition Image, Disk #4 (L:, EFI, Unformatted 16MB, and C:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtyJ9.png)

What the machine refers to as 'Drive L', it shouldn't really have a drive-letter at all.  Is 449MB, and it obviously used to be a 'System Recovery' partition.  What had happened was, it was cloned from a failed, drive that I was able to save.  And then there is '16mb of unformatted' space... Not sure if I need that or not.  It might have served a purpose before.  Since Drive-L does have a letter, I can go in and show you this:

[Drive L (System Recovery Contents)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcKsd.png)

But I'm sure it is not being used correctly in this format, as a 'Data Partition'.

Just to be clear: The 'EFI', and the 'C:' partitions, appear to be working correctly.  It's the other two, that are questionable.

So the question is how to restore these partitions correctly?

And No... I don't want to rebuild my entire C-Drive.  So if that's the answer, than.. no thanx.  I'm good.

If its not possible to recreate a recovery-partition.  Than I should just delete those partitions and merge them?

Comment: Cloning a failed drive is probably the reason.

Comment: Yes, of course its the reason... Except, reason for?  I suppose you mean the reason for the extra partitions.  Ok, well, what should/can I do with them.

Comment: ok... So its a GPT disk, booting UEFI.  It does not need a 'System Reserved' Partition.  I deleted that (L-Drive-Partition) and expanded the EFI partition.  
The error that prompted me to show up here was todo with a 'Windows-Update'  0x800F0922 .  But I no longer think it has anything to do with the partition structure.